# Magento 2.3.5: Href link visible when a non confirmed user tries to login

Tags: customer-account, bug, link, frontend-error, magento2.3.5-p1

When Store confirmation is required after customer registers and tries to login in to confirm their account, it shows an error message with a link in `here.

Please refer below screenshot

[image]

Comment: Please share your code ...

Comment: This is occurring in default Magento 2.3.5-p1

Answer (score 0):

Anybody got an idea?
Same problem here